# Removing decimals from division result

Tags: decimal, division

I am currently developing a game, and I have a small problem.
When a player buys an item from a shop, I set it to be sold at 75% the buying price.
But when the value is checked (before selling the item) it says, for example, "Can be sold for 115.0 gold" 
How do I remove the ".0" from the "115"?
I'm still new to coding, any help is appreciated.
(It's also shown with brackets, I would like to remove those as well. In example: "You can sell this for (120.0) gold pieces.")

Edit: This is java.

```
  int ShopValue = (int)Math.floor(getItemShopValue(removeId, 1, removeSlot));
    String ShopAdd = "";
    if (ShopValue >= 1000000000) {
        ShopAdd = " (" + Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1000000000) + " billion)";
    } else if (ShopValue >= 1000000) {
        ShopAdd = " (" + Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1000000) + " million)";
    } else if (ShopValue >= 1000) {
        ShopAdd = " (" + Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1000) + "k)";
    } else if (ShopValue >= 100) {
        ShopAdd = " (" + Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1) + ")";
    } else if (ShopValue >= 10) {
        ShopAdd = " (" + Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1) + ")";
    }  
    c.sM(c.getItems().getItemName(removeId)+": shop will buy for <col=255>"+ShopAdd+"</col> coins");
}
```

}

Comment: What programming langauge are you using?

Comment: @aflasin gives you the answer : Math.floor() returns a double that will be displayed as such, to display it as integer, use ((int) Math.floor(..) ).

Answer (score 0):

simple way is use a integer type cast

```
(int)Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor` is returning **double** parameter so u have to just convert it to int before you give it to  `ShopAdd` **string**.

Comment: How would I do that? (Sorry, I'm still a newbie, I've tried many things.)

Comment: `int flooredNumber = (int)Math.floor(ShopValue*.75 / 1000000000);
shopAdd = flooredNumber + " billion";`
just like that